# Create bootable SD card with Rufus

Tags: linux, formatting, sd-card, bootable-media, rufus

When create bootable SD card with Rufus utility, should be always selected formatting card (by checking "Quick format" box), or it's possible write linux OS image (.img) without formatting SD card? Because I already formatted new SD card with dedicated [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)  tool. If I select "Quick format" box on Rufus, SD card will be formatted repeatedly? What is proper way in this case?

Comment: Don't afraid of formatting by Rufus, it takes only some kbytes, not physically
format/rewrite the whole card, only the requested sectors. You can do this hundreds of times, not kill your card.

Comment: Not a problem, but SD Association recommended to use the SD Memory Card Formatter to format SD/SDHC/SDXC cards rather than using formatting tools provided with individual operating systems (since other formatting tools may not be optimized for SD cards and it may result in lower performance).

Comment: If formatting with Rufus lowers SD card performance then you should talk to the developers. I didn't see any performance issue.

Comment: What the "SD Association" says it's a moot point here because using Rufus or any other similar tool will inevitably write a new partition or partitions to the drive thus overriding anything you did before.